# Is it a best practice to keep copies of the device state in thing shadow and a database like DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

Is it a best practice to keep a copy of the device shadow in a database like DynamoDB?

- This would be helpful when we have to query on the aggregated device
  data. For Eg. "GET me all the devices with state='ON'"
- The problem here would be synchronising the copies of data in the
  device shadow and database

Any suggestions on this?﻿

Comment: It really depends on your usage. If you are going to support a very large user base and the states of the devices are changing very rapidly, you will need a very high provisioned throughput($$$) to support the operation.

Comment: Just follow the standard best practices for DynamoDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html

Answer (score 3):

Launched in December 2017, [AWS IoT Fleet Indexing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-indexing.html) supports indexing your Things and Shadows. This service automatically detects changes in your Things/Shadows and updates your index. You can perform powerful queries over this index using a subset of [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview), a popular open source search query language.

To try this feature you can call the [update-indexing-configuration API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/update-indexing-configuration.html) or just simply tick a checkbox in the AWS IoT console.

Comment: Fleet indexing can get expensive fast! At scale it is better to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on on your requirements. If you need to query on the thing shadow data you should probably use a database. Dynamodb could work, again depending on your requirements. Of course you should create the necessary indexes in dynamodb so you don't need to perform a table scan.

Depending on the number of devices and the frequency of updates you might be able to store the state in a relation database in RDS. Note this option is less scalable. To synchronize the data you would have an IOT rule forward to a lambda function that performs the database update.
With dynamodb you can have the rule forward directly into dynamodb.
Only do synchronization one way (i.e. Thing state -> database) to keep it simple.

Your other options are getting every thing shadow and filtering the results yourself.